# Pandas jupyter notebook plotting many windows instead of one

Tags: pandas, plot, histogram

I am trying to plot the histogram of a pandas dataframe and overlay the histogram with a curve. I am running the code in jupyter-notebook and I find that instead of displaying one image with the histogram, overlay plot, and axes labels, I see three separate plots. I have tried ioff, savefig, but no use. The code and output are as linked in the first comment (sorry I was having trouble with stackoverflow code formatting with figure), what I would want to see is also attached (for a different dataset. desired results image courtesy: towardsdatascience).

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,4))
    # X #
    ax.set_xlabel("Value")
    # Limit x range to 0-4 
    ax.set_xlim(0, 0.03)
    # Y #
    ax.set_ylim(0,1)
    # Remove y ticks
    ax.set_yticks([])
    # Relabel the axis as "Frequency"
    ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
    # Overall #
    ax.set_title("RMS (Sky + CD model - Smooth fit)")
    # Plot histogram
    rms_df.plot(kind = "hist", density = True, bins = 15) #
    # Plot KDE
    rms_df.plot(kind = "kde")
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('res_hist_v2.svg', format='svg', dpi=1200)
```

Comment: [window 1][1]
[window 2][2]
[window 3][3]
[desired result][4]  

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ6KS.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoqLk.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAtSZ.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR38U.png

Comment: Can you try `rms_df.plot(kind = "hist", density = True, bins = 15, ax=ax)` and `rms_df.plot(kind = "kde", ax=ax)` ?